# Debugging in VS Code without breakpoints

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to use the **Visual Studio Code debugger** to run a Go application to try and understand the code base.

I have to manually set breakpoints to pause execution but doing this may result in missing some part of the code.

So I was wondering if there is a way to **pause after every line without having to manually set breakpoints**. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using gdb you can use 's' to step line by line.

Comment: Noob question- Can you use GDB within the VSCode debugger?

Also, Delve vs GDB. Which should I use?

Comment: Yes you can use gdb in the vscode terminal. You use the one you like more. I use GDB beaucuse thtas the one I know how to use.

Comment: Ok, I will try it out. Thank you.